# access my website (Nginx) Through another machine from local network

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, kubernetes, k3s

I work on K3S kuberentes cluster on ubuntu.

```
Local IP address 192.168.111.2
public IP address : 192.168.20.90
ip loadbalancer : 192.168.111.100
```

I build an Nginx with the `k3sdomain.com` domain on my K3S cluster.

I can access my `k3sdomain.com` from my machine and another computer in a local network, simply type k3sdomain.com through the browser, but I need to put my hostname On another /etc/hosts machine.

something like this:

```
192.168.111.100 k3sdomain.com
```

But it is so ridiculous if I have many clients and need to configure every client host, and how if they access through phone, etc.

I came up with how to build a DNS server and connect to my Nginx cluster, so I followed this `https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-domain-name-service-dns` instruction. I changed the nameserver IP address many times to make sure I put the correct IP. I switched to local IP:192.168.111.2, public: 192.168.20.90 or even my load balancer IP address, but it is not working.

Maybe I don't get the concept. But please let me know your thought.

2. is it normal if we can not ping our hostname or Ip load balancer from the local machine/localhost?

   ping k3sdomain.com
   ping 192.168.111.100

it will not work, but I can ping from another machine

Thank you.

Comment: Just add the DNS record to your existing DNS server. No need to set up a new one.

Comment: where can I get the old one? it will help my domain to be accessed from outside?